# How can I get Adobe Reader X (10.0.1) to save my toolbar preferences?

Tags: browser, adobe-reader, toolbar

I just upgraded to Adobe PDF Reader X (10.0.1), and when viewing PDFs in a web browser it shows them in a new 'Read Mode' by default.

This 'Read Mode' doesn't show a toolbar (Save, Print, etc in a nice menu at the top of the PDF), but instead has a limited menu that fades in and out when the mouse nears the bottom of the displayed PDF.

I spent a couple of minutes finding and setting up the toolbar the way I wanted it, but it didn't save my preferences the next time I opened a PDF in Internet Explorer 9 - and I've been through all of the options in the 'Page Display Preferences' and can't see any reference to 'Read Mode'.

If I open a PDF outside of the browser, then the toolbars are shown by default!  That's what I'm after, but in-browser.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Open **Tools** -> **Preferences** in Adobe Reader
- Select the **Internet** category
- uncheck **Display in Read Mode by default**

Comment: great - exactly what I was after, thank you  :o)

Comment: No good for me, I already had that option turned off and yet I still don't get any toolbars at all in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for a while, but now with version 10.1.0, it no longer works.

<kbd>F8</kbd> and/or clicking on the Adobe logo in the fade-in/fade-out toolbar works, but does not apply in subsequent executions.

Comment: If you found an answer, please edit your answer to make it really address the question.